# some confusion in supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis

For  $n \in \mathbb{N}$. let $$a_{n}  = \begin{cases} \ 2+ \frac{(-1)^\frac{n-1}{2}}{n} &\text{ if  n is   odd} ,\\ 1 + \frac{ 1}{2^n} & \text { if n is even } \end{cases}$$

choose the correct option

$a)$  $\sup \{a_n |n \in \mathbb{N} \} =3$ and $\inf\{a_n |n \in \mathbb{N}\} = 1$

$b)$ $\lim \sup(a_n) = 3$ and $\lim \inf(a_n) =1$

My attempt :  Both option $a)$ and $b)$  will be  correct because  Both option $a)$ and $b)$  has  same meaning

Is  it TRue ??

Any hints/solution will be apprecaited

thanks u

Comment: But my answer was true....why....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the difference, 
$$
\inf a_n = \inf_{n \geqslant 1} a_n, \liminf a_n = \lim_N \inf_{n \geqslant N} a_n,
$$
and these expressions are clearly different.

Answer (score 2):

I think you had confusion with Limit Superior and supremum definition . Both are different concept. Limit Superior ,is supremum of all subsequentanal limit  vs supremum is just supremum of sequence given.

Answer (score 1):

NO. The option b is not correct. Because lim sup $(a_n)  $ is equal 2.

But the option a is correct.